# Display images on the screen for the user to select

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect, kinect-interaction

How do I display some images on kinect display screen so that the user selects the desired image by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this tutorial [skeletal tracking](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals). Once you are able to do this, you just have to measure the time which one hand was holding on a specific location. This can be done only with Kinect data, and if that time exceeds a certain threshold you can trigger it as a button click. Get an idea of what I'm trying to explain here from the below link [virtual dressing room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PECKUemVqio)